# Numero de registros webscrapping con Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Realizando pruebas webscrapping con Beautiful Soup a Stack overflow mediante beautiful soup para obtener el titulo de cada pregunta, el resultado siempre me trae unos 12 o 13 registros. Inspeccionando el codigo HTML de la pagina, los codigos que busco ("question-summary narrow" y "question-hyperlink") se repiten muchas más veces que 12 o 13, por lo que no entiendo por qué el código no me registra todos los titulares.

Este es el codigo:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page= requests.get("https://es.stackoverflow.com/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")

tabla= soup.find(id="question-mini-list")  #El soup find me permite encontrar un elemento
titulares = soup.find_all(class_="question-summary narrow") #El soup me permite encontrar distintos elementos (2 o mas)

pregunta= [item.find(class_="question-hyperlink").get_text() for item in titulares]

base_stack= pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Pregunta":pregunta,
    })

print(base_stack)
```

Comment: Si intentas ingresar a es.stackoverflow.com haciendo web scraping, lo que visualizas es algo como esto. https://i.ibb.co/bzn3NKX/asdasd.jpg . verás que abajo se esconde un hermoso `boton`. Una solución puede ser encarar tu problema con [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) . Te permitirá hacer click en botones y ejecutar código `javascript`.

Comment: Ohhh muchas gracias! Como entraba siempre con mi cuenta logeada, nunca me dí cuenta que entrando sin cuenta aparecía ese botón.

Comment: Si se te complica la instalación, puedes publicar otra pregunta